# Elastic Search - Aggregate over several child doc types

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, aggregation

In elastic search I have a parent-child relationship. The children can be of 5 different doc types, but all have several fields in common. I am looking for a way to search for parent documents and then aggregate over child document from every child doc type within one query. Currently this would take me 5 queries.

Comment: Could you post a (preferably simplified) example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for parent documents and then aggregate over child documents from every child doc type using the following single query:

```
POST /index_name/_search            --> leave the type_name blank
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "has_parent": {
         "type": "parentType",      --> parent doc type
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}         --> search criteria for parent
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "agg_by_type": {
         "terms": {
            "size": 0,
            "field": "_type"              --> aggregate by child doc type
         },
         "aggs": {
            "agg_by_field": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "fieldName"    --> aggregate by required field
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```